# protobuffer file with many sub messages - one big file or imports?

Tags: protocol-buffers

We recently started using protobuffers in the company I work for, i was wondering what was the best practice regarding a message that holds other messages as fields.

Is it common to write everything in one big proto file or is it better to separate the different messages to different files and import the messages you need in the main file?

For example:

Option 1:

```
message A {

    message B {
        required int id = 1;
    }

    repeated B ids = 1;

}
```

Option 2:

```
import B.proto;

message A {

   repeated B ids = 1;

}
```

And in a different file:

```
message B {

    required int id = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your dataset and the usage.

if your data set is small, you should prefer option 1. It leeds to less coding for serialization and deserialization.

if your data set is big, you should prefer option 2. If the file is too big, you can't load it completely into memory. And it will be very slow, if you need only one information and you read all the information of the file.

Maybe this is helpful.